# Android kotlin onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) cause IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, kotlin, nullable, illegalargumentexception

The first Activity doesn't launch nevertheless `Bundle?`.

```
class FirstActivity : Activity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

}
```

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter bundle

This error should occur when `override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle)`

However, I fixed `override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)`

Comment: Can you show us the relevant stack trace of your exception?

Comment: By the way the exception says the parameter's name is `bundle`, however you call it `savedInstanceState`

Comment: I down vote because i didn't get what is OP intention, s/he ask with the answer already on the question

Answer (score 2):

That's error occurred at Application class, not Activity.

Need to change Bundle into "Bundle?" both Activity and Application class.

```
  override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, bundle: Bundle?) {

    }

  override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity, bundle: Bundle?) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same error when i exchange .java to .kt automatically. But the real wrong point wasn't in Activity. In my case, the wrong place was ActivityLifecycleCallbacks where some parameters missing '?' in exchanging.

Wrong:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle) 
override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity, outState: Bundle)
```

Correct:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) 
override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity, outState: Bundle?)
```